# Omniauth "with" STI and devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, omniauth

I'm figured out with no results. I have a model named User and to models with STI fan and artist, like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :confirmable, :lockable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, **:omniauthable**
end
```

and my others models

```
Class Artist < User end
Class Fan < User end
```

my routes

```
devise_for :users
devise_for :artists
devise_for :fans
```

I have a problem when try to run my server or anything else i got this error

```
Wrong OmniAuth configuration. If you are getting this exception, it means that either:

1) You are manually setting OmniAuth.config.path_prefix and it doesn't match the Devise one
2) You are setting :omniauthable in more than one model
3) You changed your Devise routes/OmniAuth setting and haven't restarted your server
```

my app is advanced and don't wanna go back and refactor it, any help will appreciate

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer can be found [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/1927#issuecomment-6392174).

Devise gets mixed up since you are calling `devise_for` for three different models and one of them is using the `omniauthable` module.

Either:

1. Remove all `devise_for` methods except for `:users`.
2. Or remove the `omniauthable` module from the user model, create your own omniauth routes and stop using devise's middleware by moving your omniauth configuration into a new file. So, instead of having this in `devise.rb`:

   ```
   Devise.setup do |config|
     config.omniauth :twitter, ENV['TWITTER_KEY'], ENV['TWITTER_SECRET']
   end
   ```

   You now have this in your new file `omniauth.rb`:

   ```
   Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
     provider :twitter, ENV['TWITTER_KEY'], ENV['TWITTER_SECRET']
   end
   ```

   [The Railscast on Simple OmniAuth](http://railscasts.com/episodes/241-simple-omniauth) should help you setting this up.

Comment: I'm having trouble getting single sign on for all three models. Devise defaults to one model and that's it. I'm using Omniauth on its own and have removed :omniauthable

Comment: What have you tried? I've updated my answer with a link to a Railscast that should be helpful.